# Decorator for forward type hint resolution

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

## Background

I frequently develop ORM libraries using the [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee) framework. On one particularly large ORM library, representing a [proprietary data format](http://www.openimmo.de/), I have a lot of coupled ORM models representing different nodes in an XML document. The library also provides de-/serialization methods for each ORM model from/to JSON and [PyXB](https://github.com/pabigot/pyxb) DOMs.

Since subordinate models need to known superordinate models for the foreign keys to be defined, I have this one-way dependency. Alas, also superordinate models need to know the subordinate models for the de-/serializations. To avoid putting all > 10,000 LOC into one humongous Python unit, I outsourced the DOM de-/serialization into mixin classes for each of the models into separate units, accessing the subordinate modules via the foreign keys of the deferred implementation, which avoids the cyclic imports.

I have [not yet found a better solution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369070/split-orm-module-without-creating-cyclic-imports-or-side-effects) to this problem.
However, this means, that I do not have the implementated classes available on the respective module level, which again means that I cannot use them for type hinting. Hence, I use strings of the respective class names for type hinting:

```py
# Class Foo not available here, since it implements FooMixin later.
class FooJSONMixin:
    @classmethod
    def from_json(...) -> 'Foo':  
        ...
```

However, this causes, that I dont't get the actual types in the method signatures in `help()` or `pydoc`, which I want.

## Solution

Hence, I implemented a small library exposing a decorator to resolve type hint strings to the actual objects. I'd appreciate your feedback on this, since I deem it rather *hacky*.

```
"""Enhanced type hinting hacks."""

from typing import _UnionGenericAlias
from typing import Any
from typing import ForwardRef
from typing import Iterable


__all__ = ['resolve_type_hints']


def _resolve_union_generic_alias(
        uga: _UnionGenericAlias, mapping: dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Any:
    """Resolve the type."""

    return _UnionGenericAlias(
        uga.__origin__,
        tuple(_resolve_type_hint(a, mapping) for a in uga.__args__),
        inst=uga._inst,     # pylint: disable=W0212
        name=uga._name,     # pylint: disable=W0212
        _typevar_types=uga._typevar_types,  # pylint: disable=W0212
        _paramspec_tvars=uga._paramspec_tvars   # pylint: disable=W0212
    )


def _resolve_type_hint(value: Any, mapping: dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
    """Resolves a type hint."""

    if isinstance(value, str):
        return mapping.get(value, value)

    if isinstance(value, ForwardRef):
        return _resolve_type_hint(value.__forward_arg__, mapping)

    if type(value) is _UnionGenericAlias:   # pylint: disable=C0123
        return _resolve_union_generic_alias(value, mapping)

    return value


def _resolve_type_hints(
        annotations: dict[str, Any], mapping: dict[str, Any]
    ) -> None:
    """Resolves type hints of the given annotations dict."""

    for key, value in dict(annotations).items():
        annotations[key] = _resolve_type_hint(value, mapping)


def _resolve_mro(mro: Iterable[type], mapping: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
    """Resolve type hints of a method resolution order."""

    for cls in mro:
        for attribute in cls.__dict__:
            try:
                annotations = getattr(cls, attribute).__annotations__
            except AttributeError:
                continue

            _resolve_type_hints(annotations, mapping)


def resolve_type_hints(obj: type) -> type:
    """Decorator to resolves type hints on classes and functions."""

    mapping = globals()
    mapping[obj.__name__] = obj

    try:
        mro = obj.__mro__
    except AttributeError:
        _resolve_type_hints(obj.__annotations__, mapping)
    else:
        _resolve_mro(mro, mapping)

    return obj
```

## Usage example

```py
from typing import Optional, Union


class Model:
    pass


class TestMixin:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls) -> 'Test':
        return cls()


@resolve_type_hints
class Test(Model, TestMixin):
    pass
    
    
@resolve_type_hints
def test(a: Optional['Test'], b: Union['Test', int]) -> 'Test':
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the problem you're trying to solve, but instead of writing:

```py
class FooJSONMixin:
    @classmethod
    def from_json(...) -> 'Foo':
        ...
```

I wanted to point out that you can do:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Type


class BaseModel:
    ...


ModelT = TypeVar("ModelT", bound=BaseModel)


class ModelMixin:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls: Type[ModelMixin]) -> ModelMixin:
        return cls()
```

At this point if you do something like:

```py
class MyModel(ModelMixin, BaseModel):
    pass
```

Then `MyModel.foo()` return type will be `MyModel`.

Basically, you're telling `mypy` that whatever class the method `foo` is called from, it will always return an instance of this class.

Hope it can help

Comment: See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544901/7786148) to learn more about `from __future__ import annotations`, or look at the [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)